# Issue on Having Multiple Sum Function with SQL Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Using MySQL database and PHP I have a table named appData and some numeric type columns which I need to have sum of them as:

```
SELECT projectID,
       lat,
       long,       
       powerline, 
       penstock, 
       road, 
       area, 
       expense 
FROM asppData 
WHERE active = 1;
```

now as you can see I have `powerline, penstock, road, area, expense` in numeric types (Km or Currency) which I need to have all sum of them can you please let me know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for only 1 row to be returned?

Comment: Is that you need `SUM(powerline),SUM(road),...`

Comment: The answers currently will return more than one row, they will give you the sums based on projectid, lat and long.  Is that what you want? or do you want the sums for all the active records?

Comment: @ paqogomez thanks for reply and exactly this is which confusing me! I need those lat long for all active records to be displayed on the map besides I need to get the sum of all active records!

Comment: Now I am not sure that this is going to give me the result!

Comment: Can you give us some sample data and your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT projectID,
       lat,
       long,       
       sum(powerline), 
       sum(penstock), 
       sum(road), 
       sum(area), 
       sum(expense) 
FROM asppData 
WHERE active = 1
group by projectID
       lat,
       long,
```